# How to prevent CSRF attack on aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms, csrf-protection

I read in an article that aspx page could be protected from CSRF using the ViewState. But in my case, that page is being called asynchronously through WebRequest API and Update.aspx mentioned below has Async="true" set.

I could not understand how I could prevent the page from CSRF attack as it does not have a ViewState.

```
var wRequest = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
wRequest.set_url("Update.aspx");
wRequest.set_httpVerb("POST");

var body = "<data>";
wRequest.set_body(body);
wRequest.get_headers()["Content-Length"] = body.length;
wRequest.add_completed(onExecuteCompleted);
wRequest.invoke();
```

Functions defined in Code behind of Update.aspx are Page_Load, BeginAsyncOperation and EndAsyncOperation. BeginAsyncOperation and EndAsyncOperation are for the async task.

How could I implement CSRF protection for Update.aspx in the above snippet?

Comment: Do you mean this article? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972969.aspx#securitybarriers_topic2

Comment: I referred "CSRF prevention in Web forms" section in this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/csrf-attack-and-its-prevention-mechanism/